# YouTube car media output not working on bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, 6.0-marshmallow, youtube

Since the latest update on my Samsung Galaxy S6 (Android 6.0.1) I'm not able to play any kind of sound from the YouTube app true my car bluetooth media output.

When I play something from my music player app it all works fine. Calling (making and receiving) also works fine.

Here are some things I noticed:

1. Music player app gives me output because I've noticed it send the music to my car by bluetooth
2. YouTube app doesn't give me output because I noticed it goes true streaming services (something YouTube it self has integrated when connection to an external device)
3. My connection to my car automatically dismisses when I play a YouTube video. And automatically reconnects when I want to play it with the music player app.

Comment: Maybe try this [SoundAbout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix). Not tested by me

Comment: Hi @beeshyams thanks for the comment. I've tried it out but unfortunatly it is not working for Youtube.